# What Does Not Count as an Action for the ば Conditional Clause

Tags: grammar, conditionals

I'm here for yet another confusing thing from the Dictionary of Japanese Grammar. In the ば conditional, it states the following:

> S2 can be a command, a request, or a suggestion, as in Exs. (e) and (f). In this case, however, S1 cannot be an action.
>
> (e) 見たければ見なさい。 If you want to see it, see it.
> (f) 出来ればこれもやってください。
> Please do this, too, if you can.

I cannot wrap my head around why the given sentences are actually not action, when they are in fact verbs.

From what I reckon though, it's because they are not exactly actions. Example (e) is the conditional of the desire form of 見る, hence what is actually being brought into question there is the desire of seeing. Meanwhile, Example (f) is the conditional of the potential form of する; hence here what is actually being questioned is the ability to do, not the act of doing it.

So to summarize; when a verb is not exactly in the indicative form, and are instead in other forms such as the desire or potential form, they are not considered actions. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying that *verb* need not be equated with *action*.  The verb *to be* in English is definitely a verb, but you're not doing anything (and if you want to say you are, then we've gone off into the land of philosophy).  Think of *action* as something actually performed, actually done.  To *verb* isn't necessary to *do*; it can also just be a *state of being*.

There's a difference between saying みる and みたい.  With みる, you're actually doing something, you're *seeing* something.  However, みたい is rather different.  There is no *doing* being done.  みたい describes, not an action, but a frame of mind, a desire for something.

It's the same with using the potential form.  When you say, 食べられる you're not really *doing* anything.  You're definitely not *eating*.  食べられる describes what you're capable of doing.

In English we don't really care about these distinctions.  So that creates a bit of a challenge.

Now, what I am not sure about is verbs like 見える and 聞こえる.  These are both *potential* forms, but they are used a bit differently.  For example,

Suppose you were out in the woods bird watching.  You could ask your fellow birdwatcher

> 鳥が見えますか？

It would sound very strange to ask

> 鳥が見られますか？

So, I wonder whether the following is grammatical.

> 鳥が見えれば写真を撮ってください

I suspect that because it **is** a *potential* form, it still falls safely within the realm where such a conditional construction is grammatical.

Comment: It should be 見えれば, not 見えば. As for the grammaticality of the sentence, it sounds no different from 鳥が来れば写真を撮ってください to me, where 来る is definitely an action (of the bird). I wonder if the book says S1 cannot be an action of the listener, the same person the command, request, or suggestion of S2 is meant for, or any action.

Comment: @aguijonazo so you’re saying in your sample くれば sounds fine?

Comment: @aguijonazo ah! so if one thinks of 鳥がみえれば as “the bird is visible” then all is good. yes, this makes good sense.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure. It doesn't sound too awful. 鳥が見えれば sounds no more, or less, grammatical in comparison.

Comment: In terms of the book (DJG), it’s grammatical when 鳥が見えれば means that you have ability to see the bird, not that you see the bird, or 鳥が見えたら.

Comment: @user4092: While that makes sense, I cannot think of a scenario where one would have to specify a person's ability to see birds as a condition for taking a photo. Then I guess 鳥が見えれば写真を撮ってください should be considered as ungrammatical as 鳥が来れば写真を撮ってください. They do sound equally awkward to me, but I cannot tell whether it is because my dialect generally prefers たら over れば and a sentence with れば tends to sound awkward to me, or there is something really wrong with it in these particular sentences. As I said, they don't sound that awful, either.

Comment: @aguijonazo I just happened to be watching an episode of "Midsomer Murders" involving some bird watchers (hence the example) in which a rare bird is spotted but no one else has seen it.  The sighting of the bird needs to be documented.  But, you're point is well taken, "If you're able to see it, take a picture" vs "If you see it, take a picture".  It seems that even in English the later sounds a lot more natural, for former just seems to be a bit pedantic and overly dramatic.  (But that's what you get in silly, yet neverthelss entertaining, murder mystery shows like "Midsomer Murders".)

Comment: I would say 鳥が見えるのであれば or 見えるのなら if I am referring to a rare condition of someone possessing an ability (supernatural or otherwise) to see the bird when others may not. I find it very difficult to interpret 鳥が見えれば写真を撮ってください in this "grammatical" way.

Comment: @aguijonazo あ、一応私自身も同じ感覚ですよ。ただ、定義的にはってことです